# Can an element with style="float: right;" be made to align to the FIRST of a series of "float: left;" elements?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a series of input fields that I'd like to sort into two columns. Sounds easy, right? Well the unfortunate bit is that these fields are all siblings inside one parent div (i.e. I can't create a new div to house each column individually), and the fields ***must*** be ordered `<left1 /> <left2 /> ... <right1 /> <right2 /> ...` in the HTML body. Suffice it to say the HTML is a limitation of a particular WordPress plugin, and I'm trying to avoid PHP in this case at all costs. That basically leaves CSS as the most viable tool here. (JS might also work, but CSS is preferable.)

The code in question looks something like this:

```css
.form-row-left {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}

.form-row-right {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Comments Mine -->
<form class="my-form-fields">

  <!-- Left "Column" Heading -->
  <h3 class="form-row form-row-left" id="primary_contact_heading">Primary Contact Information</h3>

  <!-- Left "Column" Field 1 -->
  <p class="form-row form-row-left" id="primary_contact_name">
    <label for="primary_contact_name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text " name="primary_contact_name" id="primary_contact_name" value="">
  </p>

  <!-- Left "Column" Field 2 -->
  <p class="form-row form-row-left" id="primary_contact_email">
    <label for="primary_contact_name">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text " name="primary_contact_email" id="primary_contact_email" value="">
  </p>

  <!-- Left "Column" Field 3 -->
  <p class="form-row form-row-left" id="primary_contact_phone">
    <label for="primary_contact_name">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text " name="primary_contact_phone" id="primary_contact_phone" value="">
  </p>


  <!-- Right "Column" Heading -->
  <h3 class="form-row form-row-right" id="secondary_contact_heading">Secondary Contact Information</h3>

  <!-- Right "Column" Field 1 -->
  <p class="form-row form-row-right" id="secondary_contact_name">
    <label for="secondary_contact_name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text " name="secondary_contact_name" id="secondary_contact_name" value="">
  </p>

  <!-- Right "Column" Field 2 -->
  <p class="form-row form-row-right" id="secondary_contact_email">
    <label for="secondary_contact_email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text " name="secondary_contact_email" id="secondary_contact_email" value="">
  </p>

  <!-- Right "Column" Field 3 -->
  <p class="form-row form-row-right" id="secondary_contact_phone">
    <label for="secondary_contact_phone">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text " name="secondary_contact_phone" id="secondary_contact_phone" value="">
  </p>

</form>
```

If you run the snippet, you can see that the `<h3>Secondary Contact Information</h3>` on the right aligns with the ***bottom*** `<p>` element on the left, which leaves a bunch of empty space. I can think of a couple ways to fix this by editing the HTML:

Rearranging the form elements so that elements which should be in the same "row" are consecutive (L,R,L,R):

```html
<form>
  <h3 class="form-row-left">Primary Contact Information</h3> <!-- Left "Column" Heading -->
  <h3 class="form-row-right">Secondary Contact Information</h3> <!-- Right "Column" Heading -->
  <p class="form-row-left" id="primary_contact_name"> ... </p> <!-- Left "Column" Field 1 -->
  <p class="form-row-right" id="secondary_contact_name"> ... </p> <!-- Right "Column" Field 1 -->
  etc...
</form>
```

Or to place the pseudo-columns into an actual `<div>` of their own:

```html
<form>
  <div style=" float: left; clear: left; display: block; width: 50%;"> <!-- Left Column -->
    <h3 class="form-row-left">Primary Contact Information</h3> <!-- Left Column Heading -->
    <p class="form-row-left" id="primary_contact_name"> ... </p> <!-- Left Column Field 1 -->
    etc...
  </div> <!-- End Left Column -->

  <div style=" float: right; clear: right; display: block; width: 50%;"> <!-- Right Column -->
    <h3 class="form-row-right">Secondary Contact Information</h3> <!-- Right Column Heading -->
    <p class="form-row-right" id="secondary_contact_name"> ... </p> <!-- Right Column Field 1 -->
    etc...
  </div> <!-- End Right Column -->
</form>
```

However, ***Neither of these options are available to me*** because I need to avoid using custom PHP in this WordPress site - doesn't matter why.

So, is there any way to achieve what I need, given that HTML and PHP are off-limits? Ideally the solution would be CSS-only, but JavaScript (including JQuery) is acceptable as well.

---

My apologies if this turns out to be an incredibly long-winded question with a short, simple answer. My web development skills are entirely self-taught and I haven't been doing this for long. I couldn't think of a more straightforward way to word my question so I expect I've missed an existing answer out there somewhere.

Comment: Why not using flexbox or grid to achieve this?

Comment: @HaoWu I suppose I left out something important - there are other elements inside of `<form class="my-form-fields">`  that should NOT be columnized (i.e. full-width). These have `class="form-row form-row-full"`.

Comment: That's also very easy to achieve in grid layout, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using [grid layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), check the [supportage](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid).

```css
.my-form-fields {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

.form-row-left {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.form-row-right {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.form-row-full {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<!-- Comments Mine -->
<form class="my-form-fields">

  <h2 class="form-row form-row-full">Something that not columnized.</h2>


  <!-- Left "Column" Heading -->
  <h3 class="form-row form-row-left" id="primary_contact_heading">Primary Contact Information</h3>
  <!-- Left "Column" Field 1 -->
  <p class="form-row form-row-left" id="primary_contact_name">
    <label for="primary_contact_name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text " name="primary_contact_name" id="primary_contact_name" value="">
  </p>

  <!-- Left "Column" Field 2 -->
  <p class="form-row form-row-left" id="primary_contact_email">
    <label for="primary_contact_name">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text " name="primary_contact_email" id="primary_contact_email" value="">
  </p>
  
  <h2 class="form-row form-row-full">Another one of somethings that not columnized.</h2>


  <!-- Left "Column" Field 3 -->
  <p class="form-row form-row-left" id="primary_contact_phone">
    <label for="primary_contact_name">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text " name="primary_contact_phone" id="primary_contact_phone" value="">
  </p>

  
  <!-- Right "Column" Heading -->
  <h3 class="form-row form-row-right" id="secondary_contact_heading">Secondary Contact Information</h3>

  <!-- Right "Column" Field 1 -->
  <p class="form-row form-row-right" id="secondary_contact_name">
    <label for="secondary_contact_name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text " name="secondary_contact_name" id="secondary_contact_name" value="">
  </p>

  <!-- Right "Column" Field 2 -->
  <p class="form-row form-row-right" id="secondary_contact_email">
    <label for="secondary_contact_email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text " name="secondary_contact_email" id="secondary_contact_email" value="">
  </p>
  
  <!-- Right "Column" Field 3 -->
  <p class="form-row form-row-right" id="secondary_contact_phone">
    <label for="secondary_contact_phone">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text " name="secondary_contact_phone" id="secondary_contact_phone" value="">
  </p>

</form>
```